# find fingertips and valley point of hand in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am working on palm print identification by palm texture and geometry. 
During the preprocessing step I want to detect fingertips and valley points of the hands. First we must find reference point for the trace bounding integer, after that find valley and fingertips point.

I was wondering if someone is able to help me.

This is my code:

```
I=imread(palm.jpg);
I=I(:,:,1);
h = fspecial('disk',30);
s = imfilter(I,h,'symmetric');
I1=s(:,:,1)>79;
I4=edge(I1,'canny');
 %% find refrense point
 s=size(I4);
 r=[0,0];
  for row=s(1):-1:1
        for col=1:s(2)
            if I4(row,col)==1
                r=[row,col];
                break
            end

        end
        if I4(row,col)==1
            r=[row,col];
            break
        end
    end
 b = bwtraceboundary(I4,[row col],'NW',8);
```

Comment: An example of the image you want to process would be nice.

Comment: It would also be nice if you explain the actual problem you are facing with your current code. What's the hiccup, where did you jam?

Comment: in this code there isn't any problem.i wrote this code to make it easier for writing continue of code.you can neglect to this code.

Comment: how can i upload image of palm here mr @rayryeng

Comment: @HosseinSalimi [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)